# SparkSQL/Hive: equivalent of MySQL's `information_schema.table.{data_length, table_rows}`?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

In `MySQL`, we can query the table `information_schema.tables` and obtain useful information such as `data_length` or `table_rows`

```
select
  data_length
  , table_rows
from
  information_schema.tables
where  
  table_schema='some_db'
  and table_name='some_table';

+-------------+------------+
| data_length | table_rows |
+-------------+------------+
|        8368 |        198 |
+-------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Is there an equivalent mechanism for SparkSQL/Hive?

I am okay to use `SparkSQL` or program API like `HiveMetaStoreClient` (java API `org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient`).  For the latter I read the API doc ([here](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r2.1.1/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaStoreClient.html)) and could not find any method related to table row numbers and sizes.

Comment: Hive/SparkSQL works differently than RDMS, All the data resides on HDFS. The Hive/spark uses map reduce to parse and process the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one command for meta-information. Rather there are a set of [commands](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowDatabases), you may use

**Describe Table/View/Column**

```
desc [formatted|extended] schema_name.table_name;

show table extended like part_table;
SHOW TBLPROPERTIES tblname("foo");
```

**Display Column Statistics (Hive 0.14.0 and later)**

```
DESCRIBE FORMATTED [db_name.]table_name column_name;
DESCRIBE FORMATTED [db_name.]table_name column_name PARTITION (partition_spec);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written the following code that replicates the information_schema functionality in Databrick's Hive_Metastore. Feel free to use-

```
spark.sql("Drop view if exists allColumns")

for db in spark.sql("show databases").collect():
    for table in spark.catalog.listTables(f"{db.databaseName}"):
        try:
            for column in spark.catalog.listColumns(table.name, table.database):
                cls.append([table.database,table.name, column.name, column.dataType])
                print(table," table loaded successfully")
        except:
            print("Error Loading The Table ",table," in Information_Schema")
            
spark.createDataFrame(cls, schema = ['databaseName','tableName','columnName', 
'columnDataType']).createOrReplaceTempView("allColumns")

spark.sql("""create or replace table default.information_schema as select * from allColumns""")
```